# Function printing wrong value, but is calculating the correct value

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


float ts (int a) {
    float tp;
    tp=a*60;
    return tp;
}


int ponto (float t) {
    if (t < 180)
    return 100;
    else if (t >= 180 || t <= 300)
    return 80;
    else
    return ((80-(t-5))/5);
}

int main()
{
    int quantidade,c=0, p1, p2,p3,insc;
    float tp1, tp2, tp3,t1,t2,t3;

    puts ("Informe quantidade de equipes");
    scanf ("%d", &quantidade);
    puts ("Informe tempo padrao das tres etapas respectivamente em minutos");
    scanf ("%f%f%f", &tp1, &tp2, &tp3);
    tp1 = ts (tp1);
    tp2 = ts (tp2);
    tp3 = ts (tp3);
    do {
            puts ("Informe número de inscricao da equipe");
            scanf ("%d", &insc);
            puts ("Informe tempo das tres etapas respectivamente em minutos");
            scanf ("%f%f%f", &t1, &t2, &t2);
             t1 = ts (t1);
             t2 = ts (t2);
             t3 = ts (t3);
             printf ("\nNº de inscricao: %d", insc);
             t1 = abs (tp1-t1);
             p1 = ponto (t1);
             t2 = abs (tp2-t2);
             p2 = ponto (t2);
             t3 = abs (tp3-t3);
             p3 = ponto (t3);
             printf ("\nPontos obtidos na etapa 1: %d", p1);
             printf ("\nPontos obtidos na etapa 2: %d", p3);
             printf ("\nPontos obtidos na etapa 3: %d", p3);
             printf ("\nTotal de pontos: %d",p1+p2+p3);
             c++;
    } while ( c < quantidade);
    return 1;
}
```

Why the function `ponto` return always 100 but int the total return the true value? I'm using codeblocks... The value that appears in total is the true value, but the de values that appear on etapa 1,2,3 area always 100...

Comment: can you post the sample data you entered?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to provide the test data as well but I see one immediate problem. In the line that's supposed to print out `p2`, you're actually outputting `p3`.

I'd also be wary of the mixing of floats and integers, such as passing a float to `abs()`. You'll prouu bably be better off choosing *one* data type and sticking to it.

There seems little point in inputting a float when it gets converted to an integer on the call to `ts()`, which is possibly where your problem lies.

In any case, unless you're keeping massive arrays of them, most people tend to prefer doubles over floats, due to the increased range and precision.

And, if you think long and hard about this:

```
else if (t >= 180 || t <= 300)
```

you will realise it will *always* evaluate to true. You probably meant to use `&&`, the logical AND operator.

Comment: Thanks, but in the p3 is returning always 100... know what can be?

Comment: @Iago, then you need to tell us the input data you're using.

Comment: input data? sorry, im start programming now :/

Comment: You could add that his `pronto` function doesn't work as he intended (as far as I can tell). The final else-clause will never be reached and the else-if-clause should probably have a && instead of a ||.

Comment: Thanks, im going to sleep now, tomorrow i will try again, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

to understand where is the problem, first you must tell what are the test cases that give you problems. but at first sight, i see that you must replace || with && if you want that "pontos" returns 80 when input is beetwen 180 **AND** 300